# How to find which process communicated with a certain ip at a certain time?

Tags: ip

This is probably a noobie question...

I had nethogs open, and I've got the following output

```
3001 nabil    /opt/google/chrome/chrome                   wlp6s0      0.602       0.163 KB/sec
      ? root     192.168.1.2:59844-69.172.201.153:443                    0.000       0.000 KB/sec
      ? root     192.168.1.2:59842-69.172.201.153:443                    0.000       0.000 KB/sec
      ? root     192.168.1.2:59840-69.172.201.153:443                    0.000       0.000 KB/sec
      ? root     192.168.1.2:59838-69.172.201.153:443                    0.000       0.000 KB/sec
      ? root     unknown TCP
```

the first line is because I had a chrome open, but the other 4 following lines I have no idea which process is using them. (whois on 69.172.201.153 didn't help either)
What I want to know is, which process is initiating them, and ideally the data that has been sent.

Comment: I cant comment (not enough rep) so Ill just write this in an answer. Have you tried any sniffer tools? There are a big number of them and they can capture any incoming/outgoing traffic by milliseconds and the bytes being transferred. It seems to me that its all you need. Although you would have to run whatever you want to observe for the second time under the observation of the sniffer app this time, so it can register any traffic.

Comment: right now I've blocked all ips (that seemed suspicious to me), are they logged somewhere?

Comment: the name of the process will be very useful I think

Comment: try netstat -tulpn the next time it happens.

Answer (score 1):

[Per Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143849/why-nethogs-wont-see-the-pid-of-the-processes-the-generating-some-nfs-traffic) ? PIDs are caused by network traffic that comes from the kernel it self not a process.  In their case an app reads a file over NFS, so the application just calls read and the kernel does the network connection outside of the applilcation.  Any NFS shares, or other indirect network activity going on?

Comment: How can I know that ?

Comment: @ErnestDujo If I am not mistaken mount -l will list all mounts and their type, a mount with type nfs would be a nfs share. You might also look to see if you have rpc.nfsd installed and running.